# How to find Landmarks using Goolge_ml_kit in Flutter

Tags: tensor, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

I am comparing two faces to be similar or not in Flutter.
I am using google_ml_kit: ^0.15.0.
My approach is to get the landmark map of both faces and compare the map of landmarks.
but I am always getting 0 similar landmarks.

when printing landmarks in the Run tab using debugPrint, I am getting

```
Prompted {FaceLandmarkType.bottomMouth: Instance of 'FaceLandmark', FaceLandmarkType.rightMouth: Instance of 'FaceLandmark', FaceLandmarkType.leftMouth: Instance of 'FaceLandmark', FaceLandmarkType.rightEye: Instance of 'FaceLandmark', FaceLandmarkType.leftEye: Instance of 'FaceLandmark', FaceLandmarkType.rightEar: Instance of 'FaceLandmark', FaceLandmarkType.leftEar: Instance of 'FaceLandmark', FaceLandmarkType.rightCheek: Instance of 'FaceLandmark', FaceLandmarkType.leftCheek: Instance of 'FaceLandmark', FaceLandmarkType.noseBase: Instance of 'FaceLandmark'}
```

Please suggest to me how I can compare two faces in Flutter. My aim is to create a face recognization attendance system in Flutter.

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:google_ml_kit/google_ml_kit.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  File? firstImage;
  File? secondImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () => pickImage(0),
                  child: (firstImage == null)
                      ? Container(color: Colors.grey, width: 200, height: 200)
                      : CircleAvatar(
                          radius: ScreenUtil().radius(80),
                          backgroundImage: FileImage(firstImage!))),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () => pickImage(1),
                  child: (secondImage == null)
                      ? Container(color: Colors.grey, width: 200, height: 200)
                      : CircleAvatar(
                          radius: ScreenUtil().radius(80),
                          backgroundImage: FileImage(secondImage!))),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                getSimilarLandmarks();
              },
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center, "Compare Image Landmarks"),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  pickImage(int i) async {
    try {
      final XFile? image =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      if (image == null) {
        debugPrint("No Image Selected");
      } else {
        setState(() => (i == 0)
            ? firstImage = File(image.path)
            : secondImage = File(image.path));
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Image can not be set due to: --- ${e.message}");
    }
  }

  void getSimilarLandmarks() async {
    final faceDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.faceDetector(FaceDetectorOptions(
        enableClassification: true,
        enableLandmarks: true,
        enableContours: true));
    final InputImage inputFirstImage = InputImage.fromFile(firstImage!);
    final InputImage inputSecondImage = InputImage.fromFile(secondImage!);

    final List<Face> firstImageFacesList =
        await faceDetector.processImage(inputFirstImage);
    final List<Face> secondImageFacesList =
        await faceDetector.processImage(inputSecondImage);

    if (firstImageFacesList.length > 1) {
      debugPrint("First Image has Multiple faces");
      return;
    }
    if (secondImageFacesList.length > 1) {
      debugPrint("Second Image has Multiple faces");
      return;
    }

    final firstImageLandmarks = firstImageFacesList[0].landmarks;
    final secondImageLandmarks = secondImageFacesList[0].landmarks;
    double similarityScore =
        compareMaps(firstImageLandmarks, secondImageLandmarks);

    debugPrint("SIMILAR LANDMARKS: $similarityScore");
  }

  double compareMaps(Map map1, Map map2) {
    var equalProperties = 0.0;
    for (var key in map1.keys) {
      if (map2.containsKey(key) && map1[key] == map2[key]) {
        equalProperties++;
      }
    }
    return equalProperties;
  }
}
```

My pubspec.yaml file dependencies:

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.14.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.2
  google_ml_kit: ^0.15.0
  image_picker: ^1.0.0
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.8.4
```

Answer (score -2):

For instant matching profiles, join Bar Byoli Matrimony at:
https://www.barbyoli.in/register

Download the Bar Byoli Matrimony App from the Google Play Store:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.barbyoli.mobile&hl=en_IN&gl=US

Visit our official blog for effective communication in Indian Matrimonial:
https://www.barbyoli.in/home/how-to-communicate-effectively-in-indian-matrimonial/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).